# Delete operator memory management

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am trying to understand memory management in C++.
Here's my code:

```
 Person *P5 = new Person();
 delete P5;
 std::cout<<P5->getWeight()<<std::endl;
 delete P5;
 std::cout<<P5->getWeight()<<std::endl;
```

My first cout works and the 2nd doesn't,where as I used `delete` before both. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: You might be hitting Undefined behaviour

Comment: Your last three lines invokes UB.

Comment: why would you print something out after deleting it

Comment: It's very simple.  If you've told the operating system that you aren't going to use the memory anymore, then you don't use it.  If you do anyway, you cannot guarantee anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delete P5;
std::cout<<P5->getWeight()<<std::endl; // 1
delete P5;                             // 2
std::cout<<P5->getWeight()<<std::endl; // 3
```

1. You're trying to dereference pointer that points to already realized memory. This is Undefined Behavior. Anything could happen.
2. You're trying to free already freed memory. This is Undefined Behavior. Anything could happen.
3. `goto` **1**

Answer (score 2):

Neither `cout` is guaranteed to work for you, since you use a deleted object.
It's just that sometimes, when you delete something, the memory is not overwrited, the data is still there. But it may be reused next time you allocate memory.
When you do

```
 Person *P5 = new Person();
 delete P5;
```

p5 is a dangling pointer. Just don't use it after `delete`